# Start a Delphi host application using a project-relative path and macros

Tags: delphi, debugging, macros

### Background

I use run time (plugin) BPL's and a host application. For whatever reason I sometimes need to debug my bpl without switching to the host app, so I can set the 'Host application' in the debugging options.

I have multiple versions of my project (eg maintenance and trunk) and I want to use relative paths, or preferably even de output path.
SO I set my host application (for running/debugging a bpl) to `$PATH($EXENAME)\HostApp.exe`. But it appears RS10.3 does NOT resolve these macros when trying to start the host application. (AFAIK older versions don't do this either).

It appears the same applies to the command line parameters, though something like `$(SomeEnvVar)` is expanded to `%SomeEnvVar%` on the command line.

### The question

How can I start my (host) application without using an absolute path to my binaries, within the RS10.3 IDE?

I have created an [issue on the embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23470) site. Please upvote there to shake things up :)

I created a test app, but only tests for cmdline params. Here are settings and results:

[image: Debugger settings]

[image: Results]

Sourcecode is little relevant and very elementary, but added for completeness.

```
procedure TfrmMain.DoShow;
VAR i:integer;
begin
  inherited;
  Memo1.Clear;
  for i:=0 to ParamCount-1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(i));
end;
```

Comment: These $(xx) items are environment variables. Obviously the Parameters field doesn't recognize any macros. Oh, and you can do `for I := 0 to ParamCount`. ParamStr(0) is not a parameter, it is the exe name, and params go from 1 to ParamCount. You obviously missed the last parameter.

Comment: You, I found that out too. By now I tried by passing the output path using the envinronment variables section of the debugger options. No luck there either.

Comment: I defined a new environment variable COCOLORES with value C:\Tools\ (a valid directory on my HD) and indeed, it showed as %COCOLORES% and not as C:\Tools\

Comment: Created an issue on the embarcadero site as suggested. Please upvote there to set things in motion ;)

Answer (score 2):

The *Parameters* line doesn't recognize any macros. You can use environment variables (as you can find in the *Environment Block* in the same dialog).

So if you enter *$(BDS)* or *$(APPDATA)* you will get the resolved environment variables, e.g. in my case:

```
c:\embarcadero\studio\20.0
C:\Users\Rudy\AppData\Roaming
```

That is also why *$(EXENAME)* resolves to *%EXENAME%*: it can't be resolved to the value of an environment variable.

But unfortunately, you can't use any macros like *$PATH($EXENAME)* here. They only seem to work in the *Tools | Configure Tools* dialog.

It would be nice if they could be used in the *Parameters* of the Debugger too. You could suggest it in Quality Portal.

Comment: Indeed. So it is not an A to the Q :(

Comment: An answer that tells you you can't do something is an answer too. It is not a solution for your problem, but certainly a valid answer.

Comment: So it is not a S to the P :( - ah sorry Rudy, I hit the <enter> button to quickly.. Before adding the issue to the quality portal, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel ;)